# Conversational Bot on MIcrosoft Bot Framework possible?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

Is it possible to have a conversational bot using the bot framework of Microsoft? I'm currently using Luis and Qna maker combined, but it is still pretty much a single question and answer bot, what can I do to make it more of a conversational bot? where the user can ask the bot to justify its previous answer more like a human? I've seen a a bot that is very intelligent, [Mitsuku](https://pandorabots.com/mitsuku/) how can i make my bot similar or close to this?

[image]

[image]

It appears that it can review all the previous conversation we had and it can also justify its answers pretty much well, i can pick any word from his response and it can justify why it answered that way. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do the conversation with Microsoft Bot framework. You can do this using [Microsoft Form Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.formflow.formbuilder-1?view=botbuilder-3.12.2.4) class.

You can combination of `Luis` and `FormBuilder` to get the desired result. Identify the user intent with`Luis` and then use `FormBuilder` to further get complete information.

[This](https://rahulrai.in/post/Building-Bots-with-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework---Part-3/) and [this](https://rahulrai.in/post/Building-Bots-with-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework---Part-4/) blog posts explain how you can achieve this. Also, have a look into [Advance features of Form Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-advanced) for more information.

I *don't think* it is possible to achieve this with QnA maker alone.

Comment: im using luis and qna together. but my bot is no way near like my example above, its simply a question and answer bot, if i try to pick a word from its previous answer it cant justify itself.

Comment: I don't quite get you here. Does your requirement requires a conversion or is it FAQ? If it is conversation then `FormBuilder` should matches your needs. However, if it is FAQ, then you have do not have relationship between the two questions/ chat. In that case QnA make sense.

Comment: what i want is for my bot to be more human like, right now it can answer a specific question but if the user tried to ask lets say a part of what the bot previously replied it could no longer understand it. What I aim is for it to understand previous conversations made by the user. I want it to be able to respond well like mitsuku bot. Is there an algorithm behind it? how can it answer pretty much anything you ask? please try asking mitsuku and see how witty it is.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I think what you are asking can be hybrid/ combination of `QnA`, `FormBuilder` and `Luis`. Try reading about `FormBuilder`. I have done couple of POCs with it. You can very easily achieve what mitsuku does with `FormBuilder`, perhaps even more. Give it a try.